# Agrupar ou dividir o dataframe a cada valor específico na linha

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tenho um dataframe de uma coluna e várias linhas com dados de notas fiscais e produtos com a seguinte estrutura:

```
    NF  
0   100     
1   500     
2   200    
3   200
4   100
5   500
6   200
7   100
8   500
9   200
10  100
```

O número 100 indica uma nova nota fiscal os numeros 200 e 500 são produtos dessa nota. Eu gostaria agrupar ou dividir o dataframe a cada vez que aparece o número 100. Ficando assim:

```
    NF  
0   100     
1   500     
2   200    
3   200

4   100
5   500
6   200

7   100
8   500
9   200

10  100
```

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: EBV, você conseguiu testar o meu código? chegou na resposta desejada?

Answer (score 0):

Se a ideia é agrupar as notas fiscais, você pode usar o `cumsum()` para criar um identificador/ID para todas as linhas que só muda quando um novo valor igual a 100 é encontrado

```
df['nota_fiscal_id'] = (df['NF'] == 100).cumsum()
#saida:
    NF  nota_fiscal_id
0   100 1
1   500 1
2   200 1
3   200 1
4   100 2
5   500 2
6   200 2
7   100 3
8   500 3
9   200 3
10  100 4
```